# Selecting the most popular type

Tags: postgresql

i have the following problem:

i'm having problems selecting the most popular(the one that has the highest value in count) place for each city from a table like this:

```
city    place     COUNT
 A       X1        30
 A       X5        12
 A       X3        5
 B       X1        35
 B       X2        12
 C       X1        4
 C       X4        9
 C       X2        8
```

It should return something like this:

```
CITY    PLACE
 A       X1
 B       X1     
 C       X4
```

UPDATE:
I managed to select it in a way i got this table:

```
city    place     COUNT
 A       X1        30
 A       X5        12
 A       X3        5
 B       X1        35
 B       X2        12
 C       X4        9
 C       X2        8
 C       X1        4
```

(The count values are now from the highest to the lowest according to the city. Is there a way i can select just the first values that appear for each city?

Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: i'm new to SQL, so any feedback is usefull. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the second answer to the question I marked as duplicate. Adapted to your data it would be this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ecd04/5

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :3